# Jmonkey engine 3.0 Drawing points

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

How can I draw a 3D-point (or point sprite) in 3D space?

There is no documentation for drawing a point in JMonkey Engine site or anywhere else. Just a single point. Then updating the coordinates. No color, just a dot in 3D space.

Comment: have you tried the ImagePainter SDK plugin? http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/image-getpixelsetpixel-imagepainter-editing-jme3-images/page/4/#post-300344

Comment: Thanks,I havent tried that, probably faster, but Ive already gone to opengl :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point (as opposed to a sphere) can be created using a mesh in which you directly set its buffers (or technically buffer; since a points mesh doesn't require an index buffer as other more complex meshes require. See [How can I draw a straight line in the JMonkey Engine library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424781/how-can-i-draw-a-straight-line-in-the-jmonkey-engine-library)). Mesh creation is documented [here](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:custom_meshes).

An example of creating points in 3D space using a mesh is below:

```
import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
import com.jme3.material.Material;
import com.jme3.math.*;
import com.jme3.renderer.RenderManager;
import com.jme3.scene.*;
import com.jme3.util.BufferUtils;

public class Main extends SimpleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
        app.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {

        Vector3f[] lineVerticies=new Vector3f[5];

        lineVerticies[0]=new Vector3f(2,0,0);
        lineVerticies[1]=new Vector3f(-1,0,1);
        lineVerticies[2]=new Vector3f(0,1,1);
        lineVerticies[3]=new Vector3f(1,1,1);
        lineVerticies[4]=new Vector3f(1,4,0);

        plotPoints(lineVerticies,ColorRGBA.White);
    }


    public void plotPoints(Vector3f[] lineVerticies, ColorRGBA pointColor){
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.setMode(Mesh.Mode.Points);


        mesh.setBuffer(VertexBuffer.Type.Position, 3, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(lineVerticies));


        mesh.updateBound();
        mesh.updateCounts();

        Geometry geo=new Geometry("line",mesh);
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        mat.setColor("Color", pointColor);
        geo.setMaterial(mat);



        rootNode.attachChild(geo);
    }


    @Override
    public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
        //TODO: add update code
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleRender(RenderManager rm) {
        //TODO: add render code
    }
}
```

This will create the points within pointVerticies as shown below

[image: points in 3d space]

Later if you need to update infomation in a buffer you can do so using:

```
VertexBuffer posBuffer = mesh.getBuffer(Type.Position);
posBuffer.updateData(BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(newData));
posBuffer.setUpdateNeeded();
mesh.updateCounts();
mesh.updateBound();
```

Or (much more efficiently) you can just attach your geometry to a node and move that (depending on your usage case).

**Notes**
In its most basic state the Vertex buffer expects x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3.... etc with no demarcation between where one vertex ends and the other begins. So the following would enter 3 vertices into the buffer; (1.1,1.2,1.3), (2.1,2.2,2.3) and  (3.1,3.2,3.3)

```
m.setBuffer(VertexBuffer.Type.Position, 3, new float[]{1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,3.1,3.2,3.3});
```

However the `createFloatBuffer()` method converts from an array of `Vector3f` into this form.

Also; its often possible to 'get away with' not calling `mesh.updateBound();`, however without it objects may be culled because the graphics card believes them to be off screen when actually they are visible

Comment: Thank you. This buffer thing seems faster than examples. I was using particle factory and it was inefficient. I started using buffers(several days ago) too but not this way I used color buffer too. Do you know any other kind of buffer ?

Comment: Excellent, I think it all depends on your usage case, if you have a cloud of points that all move together this is probably going to be the way to go. On the other hand if the points all move independantly I'd expect the particle factory to be better (but I have no data to support this). Currently I'm mostly using a mesh in triangles mode to create custom landscapes; that requires I set the position buffer, index buffer, TexCoord buffer, Normal buffer and Color buffer. I've not been using any other buffers beyond that though

Comment: Particle factory (or was it emmitter?) is using a separate algorithm to calculate particle randomized-rotations and some alpha-blending and some other things  that I dont need, makes some slower after 200k particles. But your  buffer approach goes 6M particles easily. Im using this in an N-body experiment with opencl calculation on multiple devices using jocl.